# Javascript Split method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, split

I have a method in javascript that use the split method to store the time in an array and then convert the time to seconds. But when I debug, the array always has first 2 elements and ignore the last one. Not sure why?

```
GetSeconds : function (time) {                    
    var timesecs = 0;
    var min = 1;                   
    var timeArray = time.split(ctx.options.separator); //this always contain 2 elements

    while (timeArray.length > 0) {
        timesecs += min * parseInt(timeArray.pop());
        min *= 60;
    }
    return timesecs;                    
}
```

`ctx.options.separator` is a variable that stores my delimiter. I was trying with ":" and time passed was "00:00:00". This method is called from another method which increments the second.

I tried it in IE, Chrome and Firebug. This behaves differently when I debug through Visual Studio (as this code is in my .net app)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sRwNN/) and everything works fine there. Are you sure, that `ctx.options.separator` works as expected?

Comment: Thanks!! Actually the problem was with `parseInt(timeArray.pop())`. parseInt was not able to parse the values greater than 8. We need to use base of 10 as `parseInt(timeArray.pop(), 10)`. Also, I guess I had timeArray.pop() in watch.

Comment: What kind of weird-o parseInt defaults to base 8?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be a browser issue if ctx.options.separator is being generated properly.
Which browser are you using?

Use this cross browser method that will make everything work as expected no matter which browser you use.
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split

It always has worked for me.